# Angular POST request to api sending [object, Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a functionality to my app that takes the products from an order and sends them to cart.. so basicaly it repeats the whole order.

I get the order successfully but am having trouble sending it back to the API with POST method.

My API call in cart.service.ts file is:

```
  repeatOrder(products: SingleOrder['izdelki']) {
    return from(Preferences.get({key: 'TOKEN_KEY'})).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
        const formData: any = new FormData();
        formData.append('products', products);
        return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}cart/repeatorder`, formData, {headers, observe: 'response'});
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.status);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          console.log('Error 400: ', err.error.message);
        }
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.authService.logout();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', {replaceUrl: true});
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  };
```

and this is the repeat purchase function in order-view.page.ts file:

```
  repeatThisPurchase() {
    this.repeatOrderArr= [...this.orderProducts];

    this.cartService.repeatOrder(this.repeatOrderArr).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('Data sent to cart: ', data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

and this is the button I use to trigger this repeatPurchase function:

```
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <ion-button color="vigros" class="purchase-btn" size="default" type="submit" (click)="repeatThisPurchase()" expand="block">Ponovi nakup</ion-button>
</div>
```

I am getting error 500 in my console in browser and the payload in Networks tab is:
***products: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]***

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the API endpoint as that is where error is, the API server is saying something wrong with what it is expecting

Comment: @MarkHomer All I know is that the API expects code, name and quantity from every product... if this makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

try not using formdata (formdata is mostly used to send files)

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);

return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}cart/repeatorder`,{ products }, { headers });
```

Do you know what your api is expecting as request body?

Comment: This is what the API expects: Product = {
  code: string;
  name: string;
  qty: number;
};

Answer (score 0):

Consult the documentation for [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append):

> *value*
>
> The field's value. This can be a string or Blob (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.

You have:

> ```
> const formData: any = new FormData();
> formData.append('products', products);
> ```

Based on the output, `products` is an array of objects (since a comma seperated list of `[object Object]` is what you get when you convert such a thing to a string).

You need to encode the data *somehow*. **The specifics will depend on how your server side code is trying to process it** but one possible approach would be to encode each object as JSON and append them one by one, using a `[]` on the end of the name to mark it as an array for PHP and some Node.js libraries:

```
products.forEach(product => {
    formData.append('products[]', JSON.stringify(product));
});
```

Again, I must emphasise that the specifics depend on your server-side code. It might be better to simply encode `products` as JSON and send an `application/json` formatted request instead of using `FormData` to send a `multipart/form-data` request.

Comment: All I know is that the API expects code, name and quantity from every product... if this makes any difference

Comment: @weinde — Not really. You need to know the specific format that it expects that data to be presented in.

Comment: This is what the API expects: Product = { code: string; name: string; qty: number; }; this is what it expects... but what I get from the API is this: izdelki: {
  code: string;
  name: string;
  kolicina: number;
  ean: string;
  em: string;
  cena: number;
  rabat1: number;
  rabat2: number;
  prednarocilo: number;
  ismail: number;
}[]; 
so i suppose I need to use some transform to create a new array that only accepts these 3 values from each product and kolicina has to become qty